# Error connection timeout in android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

My app starts.. loads.. and when it is done loading it displays only a blank page. It doesnt crash just display a blank page.
And I noticed at the logcat there is this error: Exception localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 Connection Refused
I am playing my app on another device not in an emulator.
So i am thinking it has an error on the url "localhost:8080/lab/lab1.xml"
OR it has an error on my codes.

So here is the MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tvResponse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResponse);
        new PostAsync().execute();
    }

    class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog pd;
        XMLHelper helper;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "by Es", "Loading", true, false);
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            helper = new XMLHelper();
            helper.get();
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(EventValue event : helper.events) {
                builder.append("\nWhat: " + event.getWhat());
                builder.append("\nWhen: " + event.getWhen());
                builder.append("\nWhere: " + event.getWhere());
                builder.append("\n");
            }
            tvResponse.setText(builder.toString());
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the XMLHelper.java

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLHelper extends DefaultHandler {
    /** 
     * The URL to be parsed
     */
    private String URL_MAIN = "http://localhost:8080/lab/lab1.xml";
    String TAG = "XMLHelper";

    Boolean currTag = false;
    String currTagVal = "";
    public EventValue event = null;
    public ArrayList<EventValue> events = new ArrayList<EventValue>();


    public void get() {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser mSaxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader mXmlReader = mSaxParser.getXMLReader();
            mXmlReader.setContentHandler(this);
            InputStream mInputStream = new URL(URL_MAIN).openStream();
            mXmlReader.parse(new InputSource(mInputStream));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // Exceptions can be handled for different types
            // But, this is about XML Parsing not about Exception Handling
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        if(currTag) {
            currTagVal = currTagVal + new String(ch, start, length);
            currTag = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        currTag = false;

        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("what"))
            event.setWhat(currTagVal);

        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("when"))
            event.setWhen(currTagVal);

        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("where"))
            event.setWhere(currTagVal);

        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("event"))
            events.add(event);
    }


    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        Log.i(TAG, "TAG: " + localName);

        currTag = true;
        currTagVal = "";

        if(localName.equals("event"))
            event = new EventValue();
    }
}
```

Here is the EventValue.java

```
public class EventValue {
    String what, when, where;

    public String getWhat() {
        return what;
    }

    public void setWhat(String what) {
        this.what = what;
    }

    public String getWhen() {
        return when;
    }

    public void setWhen(String when) {
        this.when = when;
    }

    public String getWhere() {
        return where;
    }

    public void setWhere(String where) {
        this.where = where;
    }



}
```

Here is the xml file lab1.xml (localhost:8080/lab/lab1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<events>

     <event>
        <what>Summer</what>
        <when>March1</when>
        <where>--</where>
    </event>

     <event>
        <what>asdasdas</what>
        <when>March 2</when>
        <where>asasas</where>
    </event>

     <event>
        <what>asdasdq</what>
        <when>asdasdx</when>
        <where>asdasdf</where>
    </event>

</events>
```

Please take a look at the codes. Thanks
**EDIT-**
it works now i am using computer IP adress but now the problem there is this new exception
**Exception:Connection Timeout**

Comment: actually its on another device so i have used the IP address. But now the problem is it display hello world and loading but after that it is still a blank page

Comment: Now it has an error of Connection Timeout

Answer (score 1):

Your error doesn't have anything to do with XML parsing. You have connection error. You are using `localhost`, which is the phone itself, of course it returns connection error. You probably meant your machine where you develop.

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead. You can read more from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

Comment: actually its on another device so i have used the IP address. But now the problem is it display hello world and loading but after that it is still a blank page

Comment: @spoderman69 again it is not error related to XML parsing (your original question)

Comment: Yup change the title. There is this new problem Exception:Connection Timeout

Comment: @spoderman69 are you sure that 1) other device is reachable from your emulator? 2) that device listens to port for all incoming connections (not just localhost)

Comment: I am not using an Emulator I am using a real device. Connected it through USB port. That is why i am using the IP Address. Now the orignal problem "localhost connection refused" is now gone. But there is a new problem. Exception:Connection Timeout

Comment: @spoderman69 replace word emulator with word device in my previous comment and read it again.